# Garethp/php-ews: access two different mailboxes associated to the same MS exchange user

Tags: php, php-ews

**Lib:** [Garethp/php-ews](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews)

**MS Exchange version:** 2016

I have two mailboxes under the same login.

mail1@example.com

mail2@example.com

Authorization:

```
$ews = API::fromUsernameAndPassword('example.com', 'mail1@example.com', 'some_pass');
```

I can reach all the folders from `mail1`, but don't know how to reach `mail2` content.

Is there any way I can access those two different mailboxes associated to the same MS exchange user?

There was similar issue on GitHub, but different lib ([jamesiarmes/php-ews](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews)): https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/issues/404

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method `setPrimarySmtpEmailAddress`. So right after logging to email account, set the email address you want to access:

```
$ews = API::fromUsernameAndPassword(
'example.com', 
'mail1@example.com', 
'some_pass'
)->setPrimarySmtpEmailAddress('mail2@example.com')->getMailbox();
```

And that is pretty much it. Further actions stay the same: get the folders, read the emails, etc.